# How to calculate or estimate total power usage by computer to serve a request?

Tags: power

I want calculate total power usage by my PC to serve a request.

Each Request needs following:

- Take 3 second to execute
- Take 40 MB RAM
- Transfer 1 MB trough network adapter
- System has Core 2 Due 2.80 GHz and the request takes 10% of theme for 3 second

Comment: 3 seconds / 3600 seconds * average total hourly power consumption of all devices involved (pc, router, etc.)... if you're talking about electrical power ;-)

Comment: Buy an energy analyzer like this http://www.electrex.it/en/products/energy-meters-energy-analyzers/pfa6411-02.html .... it's his job.

Comment: @Axeman The Femto analyzer merits being posted as an answer by itself, not just a comment. It's a nice piece of hardware, we've been using some of their analyzers for a project.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh Done :-)

Comment: What do you mean by power usage: marginal or average, and for average: under which load? Without such choices your question has no meaning.

Comment: I'm looking for a set of formula like: RAM's power usage: 40 (MB) * 3 (s) * 0.05 (Watt) = 6 Watt for RAM and do this for Board, CPU, Network and ... I'm looking for a sample solution that somebody done before

Answer (score 4):

Calculation will be way too rough to be meaningful.

You can use an energy analyzer (like [this one](http://www.electrex.it/en/products/energy-meters-energy-analyzers/pfa6411-02.html)) to measure the actual effects of your transactions on the power usage.

Comment: Upvoted... Care to provide a brief write-up on why it's a neat option, what such analyzers do and how they store a data log? That way, when that particular URL is no longer valid, this answer will still be useful. :-)

Comment: @AnindoGhosh as soon as I can...

Answer (score 4):

Measure the consumed power with a power meter for (eg.) a week, then count the number of requests from the log files during that period and divide measured power by number of requests.

This method takes into account that the server must be available while idle'ing for the next request, which feels to me as the only fair method.

Comment: Even the question is not clear for myself. But I want know how calculate power usage for a job has been done with computer.